# Missing Information When Eager Loading With Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, eager-loading

When trying to eager load the PriceGridRow, the index and value properties of PriceGridColumn are populated but the Id and the ProduceGridRowId are not. If i try to explicitly include PriceGridColumns it get duplicate columns (ie. i have 10 columns but the object returned by EF has 20) and half of the the columns returned are fully populated and the other half are not.

I've been pulling what's left of my hair trying to figure out why this is occurring. Can anyone see based on my configuration why it would be acting this way? Thanks!

The code i use to get columns are:

```
public override PriceGrid GetLoadedById(object id)
{
    var priceGrid = Entities
        Include(x => x.PriceGridRows.Select(o => o.PriceGridColumns))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == (int) id);


    return priceGrid;
}
```

Here are the classes in question

```
public class PriceGrid : DomainEntity<int>
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public List<PriceGridRow> PriceGridRows
    {
        get { return _priceGridRow; }
        set { _priceGridRow = value; }
    }
}
public class PriceGridRow : DomainEntity<int>
{
    public PriceGrid PriceGrid { get; set; }
    public int PriceGridId { get; set; }

    public ProductOption ProductOption { get; set; }
    public int ProductOptionId { get; set; }
    public List<PriceGridColumn> PriceGridColumns { get; set; }

}
```

And finally the third level of nesting

```
public class PriceGridColumn : DomainEntity<int>
{
    public PriceGridRow PriceGridRow { get; set; }
    public int PriceGridRowId { get; set; }

    public int Index { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my mapping files

```
public class PriceGridMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PriceGrid>
{
    public PriceGridMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(x => x.Description);
        HasRequired(x => x.Product);

        HasMany(x => x.PriceGridRows)
            .WithRequired(x => x.PriceGrid)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PriceGridId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}
public class PriceGridRowMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PriceGridRow>
{
    public PriceGridRowMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        HasRequired(x => x.ProductOption);
        HasMany(x => x.PriceGridColumns)
            .WithRequired(x => x.PriceGridRow)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PriceGridRowId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}
public class PriceGridColumnMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PriceGridColumn>
{
    public PriceGridColumnMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Index);
        Property(x => x.Value);
        HasRequired(x => x.PriceGridRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: Select the question tags more carefully next time. I have edited them now. They are important to improve your chance to get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove this mapping line from `PriceGridColumnMap`:

```
HasRequired(x => x.PriceGridRow);
```

which basically means that the relationship the `PriceGridRow` navigation property belongs to does not have an inverse navigation property. It is a shortcut for:

```
HasRequired(x => x.PriceGridRow)
    .WithMany()...
```

But this is in contradiction with the mapping in `PriceGridRowMap`:

```
HasMany(x => x.PriceGridColumns)
    .WithRequired(x => x.PriceGridRow)...
```

which says that the `PriceGridRow` navigation property *does have* an inverse navigation property, namely `PriceGridColumns`.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: Wow a late update but wanted to say that this fixed the issue.